# What am I doing wrong with FormArray?

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-formbuilder

In my form I will have the following elements:

1. input (checkbox)
2. code (span)
3. name (span)

These values ​​come from the server, which is why it is added dynamically.

However, I face the following problem with my algorithm:

```
core.js: 6228 ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
```

Only this error does not make sense, because the console is showing the values ​​correctly and the guy is an Array:

[image]

**MAIN COMPONENT**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'zx-create-country-form',
    templateUrl: './create-country-form.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./create-country-form.component.scss'],
})
export class CreateCountryFormComponent implements OnInit {
    createCountryForm!: FormGroup;
    dataTemp = [
        {
            code: 'BR',
            name: {
                pt_BR: 'Brasil',
            },
        },
        {
            code: 'TST',
            name: {
                pt_BR: 'tst3',
            },
        },
    ];

    constructor(protected readonly componentService: ComponentService, protected readonly formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
        this.createCountryForm = formBuilder.group({
            countries: formBuilder.array(this.addCountries()),
        });
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {}

    addCountries(): FormGroup[] {
        const formsGroups: FormGroup[] = [];

        this.dataTemp.map(country => {
            formsGroups.push(
                this.formBuilder.group({
                    radio: this.formBuilder.control([{ value: false, disabled: true }], [Validators.requiredTrue]),
                    code: this.formBuilder.control(country.code, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(1), Validators.maxLength(2)]),
                    name: this.formBuilder.control(country.name.pt_BR),
                })
            );
        });

        return formsGroups;
    }
}
```

**CHILD COMPONENT**

```
<zx-form [fmGroup]="fmGroup">
    <div [formArrayName]="fmArrayName" *ngFor="let country of fmGroup.controls.countries; let i = index">
        <div [formGroupName]="i">
            <input formControlName="radio" placeholder="Item name" />
            <input formControlName="code" placeholder="Item name" />
            <input formControlName="name" placeholder="Item name" />
            eqqe
        </div>
    </div>
</zx-form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see you

```
countries: formBuilder.array(this.addCountries()),
```

this.addCountries must return an Array of FormGroups. If you use map, you get a new array in witch element is a transform of the original array. So

```
return this.dataTemp.map(country => 
                this.formBuilder.group({
                    radio: this.formBuilder.control([{ value: false, disabled: true }], [Validators.requiredTrue]),
                    code: this.formBuilder.control(country.code, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(1), Validators.maxLength(2)]),
                    name: this.formBuilder.control(country.name.pt_BR),
                })
        );
```

Using a forEach, you loop over the array and make "something" with each element, as you are trying

```
    const formsGroups: FormGroup[] = [];

    this.dataTemp.forEach(country => {
        formsGroups.push(
            this.formBuilder.group({
                radio: this.formBuilder.control([{ value: false, disabled: true }], [Validators.requiredTrue]),
                code: this.formBuilder.control(country.code, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(1), Validators.maxLength(2)]),
                name: this.formBuilder.control(country.name.pt_BR),
            })
        );
    });
```

Another point of attention is how iterate in the .html, you need iterate over the controls of the form Array, for this, create a getter of the array

```
get myArrayForm()
{
     return this.fmGroup.get('fmArrayName') as FormArray
}
```

And iterate over myArrayForm.controls, but get out the formArray name, and see that it's not enclosed by []

```
<div formArrayName="fmArrayName">
   <div *ngFor="let country of myArrayForm.controls; let i = index">
        <div [formGroupName]="i">
            <input formControlName="radio" placeholder="Item name" />
            <input formControlName="code" placeholder="Item name" />
            <input formControlName="name" placeholder="Item name" />
            eqqe
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Really it's not good explain in the official docs, but you can see,e.g. [this Netanel Basal's entry](https://netbasal.com/angular-reactive-forms-the-ultimate-guide-to-formarray-3adbe6b0b61a)

**Updated** to validae if at least one of the elements of the array is true we need create a custom validation of the own array you can create the validator in the own component

```
  atLeastOne()
  {
    return (formArray:FormArray)=>{
      return formArray.value && formArray.value.filter(x=>x.radio).length<=0?
            {error:"At least one"}:null
    }
  }
```

And you use when you create the form

```
createCountryForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    countries: this.formBuilder.array(this.addCountries(), this.atLeastOne())
  });
```

NOTE: When we create a custom validator over a FormArray, we need take account that this is checked each time the formArray (or any of this FormGroups or Forms controls change)

Comment: You can complete the following in your answer: How to validate this form with multiple radio inputs? The logic would be as follows: You have several radios, but the form will only be valid when one of them is clicked.